# AngularJS how to assign response data to a variable

Tags: angularjs

How can i assign the response  to a variable or $scope. Here i want to assign the response to data variable

here is the screen shot
[image]

```
'use strict';

`var dashModule = angular.module("Student");`

    dashModule.controller("studentDashboardCtrl",
       ['$scope', 'authService', 'StudentService',
           function ($scope, authService, StudentService) {
               //Check authorised user
               var data;
               authService.checAuthentication();
               StudentService.getBatchList(function (response) {
                   console.log(response);

               });


           }]);
```

Comment: You will probably need to init the variable first: var data = {}; or var data = []; then you can do data = response;

Comment: @gyc your right Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in $scope variable,

- $scope.value=response;

Answer (score 0):

```
var dashModule = angular.module("Student");

dashModule.controller("studentDashboardCtrl",
   ['$scope', 'authService', 'StudentService',
       function ($scope, authService, StudentService) {
           //Check authorised user
           var data =[];
           authService.checAuthentication();
           StudentService.getBatchList(function (response) {
               console.log(response);
               data.push.response; //just like that you can store the response

           });


       }]);
```

Comment: if i use 
console.log(data); after StudentService.getBatchList(function (response) {
               console.log(response);
               data = response; //just like that you can store the response

           });
it shows undefined .

Comment: can u share your response?

Comment: or you can use this  self.data = response.data;

Comment: @Muhammad.NazmulAhsan Actually to store the response to the data is the way i used is correct if the response is not showing anything then you have check what is wrong in that

Comment: can u share your dummy reponse ?

Comment: @Muhammad.NazmulAhsan the problem is the StudentService `services` you can not define the variable to the service in controller part you should just call like this `StudentService.getBatchList()` what ever you want to do you should to with `StudentService.setBatchList(response)` in here only

Comment: add inside Controller function                                                                                           var self = this;

Answer (score 0):

Actually i am checking the result using console.log(); But it always shows undefined. though my approach was right. I am still confused why console.log() shows undefined. But the view shows the value correctly. Here's the code

```
  'use strict';
var dashModule = angular.module("Student");

dashModule.controller("studentDashboardCtrl",
   ['$scope', 'authService', 'StudentService',
       function ($scope, authService, StudentService) {
           //Check authorised user
           var names;
           authService.checAuthentication();
           StudentService.getBatchList(function (response) {
               $scope.names = response;
           });
              console.log($scope.names);
       }]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You Should Use this.

```
$Scope.myvariable  = response;
```

Comment: Dont post two times the answer

Answer (score -1):

```
var Module = angular.module("Student");

 dashModule.controller("studentDashboardCtrl",
  ['$scope', 'authService', 'StudentService',

   function ($scope, authService, StudentService) {
       //Check authorised user
       var self = this;
       authService.checAuthentication();
       StudentService.getBatchList(function (response) {
           console.log(response);
           self.data = response.data; 

       });


   }]);
```